# How to filter an NSArray using a NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate

I am trying to filter an array of NSDictionaries that I have.

This is what my filter currently looks like:

```
NSDictionary *selectedItemDictionary = [sortedItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSMutableArray *sortedItemsMutableArrayCopy = [sortedItemsArray copy];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dpc like %@", [selectedItemDictionary objectForKey:@"dpc"]];
[sortedItemsMutableArrayCopy filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This is what my `selectedItemDictionary` looks like:

```
dc = 3;
Cmp = F;
Qty = 0;
dp = 0;
```

Effectively I am trying to search through sortedItemsArray and make a new array of anything that has the same dc number as the selected row in my UITableViewCell. However with the code above I am receiving this error:

```
 -[__NSArrayI filterUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filterUsingPredicate:` is a method for NSMutable array you are looking for `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`

you can tell from the console output `__NSArrayI` that you have an immutable array instance.

if you want a mutable array you need to change `[sortedItemsArray copy]` to `[sortedItemsArray  mutableCopy]`

Comment: yep thats exactly what I just realised now looking at the apple docs again.. thanks very much for your answer will mark it correct soon.